# Conditional formatting of a cell based on value in 4 adjacent cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get a cell **`C3`** to highlight using conditional formatting, but based on a value in 4 other cells.

If 4 continuously adjacent cells (e.g. **`AS3`**, **`AT3`**, **`AU3`**, **`AV3`**) contain the *`X`* value only then do I want the cell **`C3`** to highlight, so NOT if they are not joined together.

(It's a worksheet to highlight absences, 4 times in a row).

How would I go about this?

Comment: I just answered the question for 4 adjacent cells, but then read it again and think I may have misunderstood. I read it as you were looking to check those 4 cells given. OR is this a whole row of cells involved where you are searching for 4 consecutive `x` vales within that row? Can you please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your range of data (with possible "x"s) is in `D3:EC3` then use this formula in conditional formatting

`=COUNTIFS(D3:DZ3,"x",E3:EA3,"x",F3:EB3,"x",G3:EC3,"x")`

because it **offsets** each range by 1 it will only give a positive count when you have a run of at least 4 consecutive "x"s in that range. A positive number triggers the conditional formatting

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a formula in the conditional formatting to check the cells are all containing `X` (assuming that is the value you are checking for).

To check more than one cell use the `AND` function which looks to see if more than one logical criteria are met. If so it returns TRUE. Syntax for this function: `AND(logical1,logical2, ...)`

To add the rule, do the following;

1. Select cell `C3`.
2. Choose NEW RULE from the Conditional Formatting menu.
3. Choose "Use formula to determine which cells to format".
4. In the box for "Format values where this formula is true:" enter the
   formula needed. (I've given an example below).
5. Click the <kbd>Format...</kbd> button and select the formatting you
   desire.
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> twice to save it.
7. Test it by entering "X" in the cells.

[image]

[image]