# How do I superimpose a conditional formated heatmap based on one set of values over a different set of values in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, colors, conditional-formatting

I would like one cell to be formatted with a gradient color based on the value in another cell.  For example, I would like cells `A1` and `A2` to be highlighted based on the values in `B1` and `B2`.  If I choose the red to yellow to green highlighting (i.e., "Color scales" under "Conditional Formatting") in Excel I would expect that if `B1 = 1` and `B2 = 2` then `A1` would be highlighted red and `A2` would be highlighted green.  Essentially, I want to build a heatmap with one set of values in a table and superimpose that heatmap over a separate, equally sized table of values.

I have seen a variety of posts discussing how to get a cell formatted in a non-dynamic way based on another cell (e.g., [here](https://superuser.com/questions/442698/change-cell-color-based-on-other-cell-value) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/665228/conditional-formatting-of-a-cell-based-on-value-in-4-adjacent-cells)) but I cannot find a description of how to do what I want to do here.  Is it possible?

If it's not possible to set up a formula for this I would be happy to copy the color-scale colors in `B1:B2` over to `A1:A2`, but I can't find a way to do that, either.

Answer (score 0):

This should work when you paste it in `Developer -> Visual Basic`, under the sheet you're working in. Make sure to change the range.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Rng = Range("A1:B2")
    If Application.Intersect(rng1, rng2) Is Not Nothing Then
        Dim Min, Max, Index As Double
        Dim Red, Green As Integer
        Dim Cell As Range
        Dim Rng As Range
        Min = Minimum(Rng)
        Max = Maximum(Rng)
        For Each Cell In Rng
            Index = (Cell.Value - Min) / (Max - Min)
            Red = 255 * ListMin(1, 2 - 2 * Index)
            Green = 255 * ListMin(1, 2 * Index)
            Cell.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset).Interior.Color = RGB(Red, Green, 0)
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
Function Maximum(Cells As Range)
    Maximum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells)
End Function
Function Minimum(Cells As Range)
    Minimum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Cells)
End Function
Function ListMax(ParamArray Values() As Variant)
    ListMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Values)
End Function
Function ListMin(ParamArray Values() As Variant)
    ListMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Values)
End Function
```

Most of this should be fairly self-explanatory, feel free to comment if you have any questions.